# What is this pattern of copying the array before iterating?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, rxjs

```
const { observers } = this;
const len = observers.length;
const copy = observers.slice();
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  copy[i].next(value);
}
```

Reading through the rxjs source code here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts I see this pattern and I am wondering what is the point of copying the array and then iterating over the array?

Why not just iterate the array?

Comment: Can't speak as to the reasons for this implementation detail, but my guess would be that calling the observers (`.next(value)`) could have the effect of modifying the original array. (someone might subscribe/unsubscribe during the call) which would lead to handlers not being called as expected

Comment: In most of the scenarios, we copy/clone objects/arrays to avoid mutations.